# Prove that there do not exist 2 integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2-b^2=n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

so i have this question:
Let n be an even integer.

(a) We assume that $n/2$ is odd. Prove that there do not exist two integers $a$
and $b$ such that $a^2-b^2=n$

(b) We assume that $n/2$ is even. Prove that there exist two integers a and b
such that $a^2-b^2 = n$

we start by saying that a and b should both be odd or even so that n is even so if a and b are even then $a^2$ and $b^2$ are also even and $a^2=4k^2$ and $b=4L^2$ then we get that $4(k^2-L^2)=n$ => $2(k^2-L^2)$=$n/2$ which is a contradiction as even does not equal odd and we repeat the process with a and b are odd we get the same result which means they do not exist

as for B. we do the same thing as A but this time it will end with an even=even so a and b exist

this is the right solution?

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/LkIK8f4yvOU) was released 2 hours ago, and more or less covers this and other "difference of two squares" things.

Comment: For (b) look at $(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2=4k$

Answer (score 3):

You can do it that way, but let me offer an argument that's easier to keep tidy. Since $(2n)^2=4n^2,\,(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1$, a square is a multiple of $4$ or $1$ more than one. So the difference of two squares can't be $2$ more than a multiple of $4$, but it can be $4n=(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $$a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$$

Note that $ a-b$ and $a+b$ have the same parity, that is either both are even in which case $ a^2-b^2=n$ is a multiple of $4$ or they are both odd in which case $a^2-b^2=n$ is odd.

Thus there is no solution to $a^2-b^2=n$ for which $n$ is an even integer where $n/2$ is odd.